# Linked List display function doesn't show all nodes and says next node is null

Tags: c++, linked-list

**Output:**

> The intial 4-node list contains:
>
> Head pointer = 17357680
> Node #1: Item = 20; Next = 00000000

I don't know if I connected the nodes correctly since it's not displaying the next one out of a total of 4. I've seen other programmers add a tail node; is one needed? Does it make something easier? Did I even connect the nodes properly in my for loop? I'm new to this and I'm lost after looking through a lot of documentation, youtube videos, and reading past stackoverflow questions.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Node
{
private:
    T        item;
    Node<T>* next;
public:
    Node();
    Node(const T& anItem);
    Node(const T& anItem, Node<T>* nextNodePtr);
    void setItem(const T& anItem);
    void setNext(Node<T>* nextNodePtr);
    T getItem() const;
    Node<T>* getNext() const;
};

template<class T>
Node<T>::Node() : next(nullptr)
{}

template<class T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& anItem) : item(anItem), next(nullptr)
{}

template<class T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& anItem, Node<T>* nextNodePtr) : item(anItem), next(nextNodePtr)
{}

template<class T>
void Node<T>::setItem(const T& anItem)
{
    item = anItem;
}

template<class T>
void Node<T>::setNext(Node<T>* nextNodePtr)
{
    next = nextNodePtr;
}

template<class T>
T Node<T>::getItem() const
{
    return item;
}

template<class T>
Node<T>* Node<T>::getNext() const
{
    return next;
}

template <class T>
void display(Node<T> *hdptr)
{
    Node<T>* curr = hdptr;
    while (curr != nullptr)
    {
        int count = 0;
        count++;
        std::cout << "Node #" << count << ": Item = " << curr->getItem() << "; Next = " << curr->getNext() << std::endl;
        curr = curr->getNext();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node<int>* hdptr = nullptr, *tmp = new Node<int>, *n = new Node<int>;

    int const nodes = 4;
    for (int i=0, num=20; i<nodes; ++i, num+=10)
    {
        n = new Node<int>;
        n->setItem(num);
        tmp = n;

        if (hdptr==nullptr)
        {
            hdptr = n;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp->setNext(n);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "The intial 4-node list contains: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nHead pointer = " << int(hdptr) << std::endl;
    display(hdptr);
}
```

Comment: `tmp = n;` followed by `tmp->setNext(n);`. Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think about this

```
tmp = n;
```

followed shortly by

```
tmp->setNext(n);
```

Since `tmp` == `n` in effect you are doing this

```
n->setNext(n);
```

which is obviously wrong.

Do you need a tail node pointer? It depends on where you are trying to add your nodes. If you are trying to add them to the end of the list then you need a tail node pointer for convenient access to the end of the list. But if you are trying to add your new nodes to the front of the list then a tail pointer would only complicate things.